# Covariance matrix of least squares estimator $\hat{\beta}$

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance

I read that the $Cov(\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2(Z'Z)^{-1}$, where $\hat{\beta}=(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'y$. However, I have yet been unable to find a proof of this fact online. Could anyone please provide a proof and/or a reference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A good reference is Greene, *Econometric Analysis*.  You should be able to pick up an older version (sixth edition or before) online for relatively cheap.  Seventh is not noticeably better than sixth.  I am changing your notation $Cov(\hat{\beta})$ to 
$V(\hat{\beta}_{\textrm{OLS}})$, but I mean the same thing by it.

Here is the proof:

If

1. $Y=Z\beta+\epsilon$
2. $E\left\{\epsilon|Z \right\}=0$
3. $V\left(\epsilon|Z \right)=\sigma^2I$
4. The OLS estimator exists and is unique (i.e. $Z'Z$ invertible)

then the OLS estimator is unbiased for $\beta$ and 
$V\left(\hat{\beta}_{\textrm{OLS}}|Z \right)=\sigma^2(Z'Z)^{-1}$.

Proof:
Using the definition of the OLS estimator and then substituting in using 1:
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}_{\textrm{OLS}} &= \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'Y\\
                           &= \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'\left( Z\beta+\epsilon \right)\\
                           &= \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'Z\beta 
                              + \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'\epsilon\\
                           &= \beta + \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'\epsilon
\end{align}
Taking expectations of both sides conditional on $Z$ gives you that the OLS estimator is unbiased.  Taking variances on both sides conditional on $Z$ gives you:
\begin{align}
V\left( \hat{\beta}_{\textrm{OLS}} | Z \right)
   &= V\left( \beta + \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'\epsilon | Z \right)\\
   &= V\left(\left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'\epsilon | Z \right) \\
   &= \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'V\left(\epsilon | Z \right) Z \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1} \\
   &= \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'\sigma^2I Z \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1} \\
   &= \sigma^2\left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}Z'Z \left( Z'Z\right)^{-1} \\
   &= \sigma^2\left( Z'Z\right)^{-1}
\end{align}
QED

This does not quite give you what you asked for, since the variance is conditional on $Z$ rather than unconditional.  If you want the variance to be unconditional, you have to additionally assume that $Z$ is fixed, so that the conditional variance becomes just an unconditional variance.  On the other hand, this is the right variance conditional on the dataset you used to estimate $\beta$ with OLS, and inference based on this variance gives (asymptotically, if you don't assume $\epsilon$ normal) you correctly-sized hypothesis tests and confidence intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain to me why you could treat $\beta$ as a constant (I'm referring to the second equality of the last block of derivations)?

Comment: $V(const + W) = Var(W)$ is a property of variance operator. Basically, constant terms do not appear since $V(const + W) = E[(const + w - E[const + W])^2] = E[(W - E[W])^2] = V(W)$.

Comment: @Theja Thanks but that was actually not what I meant. I know about that property, but what I tried to ask is why $\beta$ *can be seen as a constant*. Isn't it some kind of random variable?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I am confusing $\beta$ with $\hat{\beta}$ which *is* a random variable. Never mind then :).

Comment: $\beta$ is the true unknown model which is *assumed* to be fixed and not random (see point 1. in the answer above).

Comment: @rbm Well, if you are a Bayesian, then you are going to see that step as a mistake (I think---but ask a Bayesian to be sure).  If you are a Frequentist, parameters are always constants.

Answer (score 6):

This is the expression for the *conditional* variance-covariance matrix of the estimator. For the model $$Y=Z\beta + U, \; E(U\mid Z) =0,\; E(UU'\mid Z) = \sigma^2I$$ 
we have 
$$\operatorname {Cov}(\hat\beta \mid Z)=\operatorname {Cov} \left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'y\mid Z\right]$$

$$=\operatorname {Cov} \left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'(Z\beta +U)\mid Z\right] = \operatorname {Cov} \left[\beta +(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\mid Z\right] = \operatorname {Cov} \left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\mid Z\right] $$

Since $\beta$ is treated as a constant in the frequentist approach. Now

$$\operatorname {Cov} \left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\mid Z\right] = E\Big\{\left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U\right]\left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\right]'\mid Z\Big\} - E\left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\mid Z\right]E\left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\mid Z\right]'$$

Since 
$$E\left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\mid Z\right]' = (Z'Z)^{-1}Z'E\left[U\mid Z\right]' = 0$$
we are left with

$$\operatorname {Cov} \left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\mid Z\right] = E\Big\{\left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U\right]\left[(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'U)\right]'\mid Z\Big\} $$

$$= (Z'Z)^{-1}Z'E(UU'\mid Z)Z(Z'Z)^{-1}= (Z'Z)^{-1}Z'\sigma^2IZ(Z'Z)^{-1} $$

$$=\sigma^2(Z'Z)^{-1} $$

Comment: Could you explain why $E(UU'\mid Z) = \sigma^2I$ does that imply that the variance of each error term is equal to $\sigma^2$? I rather thought that it should be a diagnoal matrix. Which assumption is this (uncorrelated errors + Normal distribution?)?

Comment: @MrYouMath $I$ is the identity matrix and so it is diagonal. This is the "homoskedastic and uncorrelated errors" assumption. Normality is not assumed.