# $\text{var}(\hat{u})\text { and }\text{var}(\hat{Y})$ derivation

Tags: regression, variance, predictive-models, econometrics, error

Could anyone provide me with either the steps for derivation for these formulae or a textbook that covers these ols derivations?

The textbook i’m currently using does not go over this.

$$\text{var}(\hat{u})=s^2\left[1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x_{0}-\bar{X})^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar{X})^2}\right]$$

$$\text{var}(\hat{Y})=s^2\left[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x_{h}-\bar{X})^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar{X})^2}\right]$$

Comment: Sure: just [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+variance+formula).  We have a lot of threads about regression formulas ;-).

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Do you have any links to threads about these specific formulae as I couldn’t find them? Appreciate it.

Comment: The key is to refine the search to suit your needs -- you might want to exclude matrix formulas, for instance.  As an example, by including "least squares" in the search I found https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109846/.